# Razor C# - Create Table with Pages

Tags: c#, razor, html-table, razor-pages

I was wondering if it is possible to create a table with pages in C# razor? I want to make a page for every 5 workitems so that the table doesn't get too long.

My table looks like so:

```
<table class="Table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Item Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach(var workItem in workItemList)
    {
      <tr @onclick="@(() => WorkItemSelected(workItem))">
        <td>@workItem.Id</td>
        <td>@workItem.Title</td>
        <td>@workItem.ItemType</td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  You'd either build the functionality or you'd use some kind of 3rd party table plugin/component which has the functionality build-in already.

Comment: There are three approaches to this. The first is to deliver the five first records in your model, expose paging links, and then filter the workitems on the server. The second is to deliver _all_ of your records in your model, and implement the paging on the client; there are a lot of JavaScript libraries that will do exactly that. The third is to use AJAX, where the data is requested via a web API, and then bound on the client. The second approach is probably the simplest, and may even be the preferred option if you have a limited number of records (e.g., <≈500).